# How to convert a class-based lifecycle method to a functional method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, class, expo

In the following code:

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
    this._notificationSubscription = Notifications.addListener(this._handleNotification);
  }
```

what's the difference between assigning `Notifications.addListener(this._handleNotification);` to `this._notificationSubscription` and simply going:

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
    Notifications.addListener(this._handleNotification);
  }
```

Also, how do you convert it into a functional component format like the following?

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
        Notifications.addListener(handleNotification);
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
        registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
        const subscription =Notifications.addListener(handleNotification);
        return () => {
            // Call method for clear subscription. I asume that it is remove but it can be another
            subscription.remove()
        }
    }, []);
```

Comment: More info on this link: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup